# Get closest parent dtype of two ndarray's

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to convert potentially mixed (i.e. `dtype==object`) numpy arrays to the closest parent dtype (as per the hierarchy shown here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html).

[image]

Is there a built-in function (or easy way) to get the (least generic) parent type that is common to two dypes? Obviously, I can't trust the dtype of the array (because it may be object which doesn't reveal too much about the element's types).

Comment: Numpy should already upcast to the most common type, e.g. `np.array([1,2.,'3'])` -> `dtype='<U32'` ;  `np.array([1,2.])` -> `dtype='float64'`

Comment: If this isn't what you want, please provide clear examples.

Comment: `object` dtype is like lists, can be anything, numbers, strings, lists.other arrays, etc.  There's no 'closest' numeric dtype.

Comment: @mozway I want to turn `np.array([1,2.], dtype=object)` into a float array. Essentially, I'm after the upcast logic. `np.array([1,2., 'foo'], dtype=object)` needs to stay `object` (as that's the common type).

Comment: `assert np.array(np.array([1,2.], dtype=object).tolist()).dtype == float` would work, but that's using an intermediate list which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? This looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: `np.result_type` might do the job.

Comment: `object` isn't the common type.  'str' is.  `object` is a fallback dtype used to hold elements that don't otherwise have a dtype.  Values are stored as references, as in lists.